# Selenium - Element not visible when the browser set to mobile responsive mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am testing the browser for mobile responsiveness. I changed the browser window size to iPhone 5 which is 320 x 568 using this command

`driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(320, 568);`

When I run the test, the browser opens fine according to the mentioned size without any issue. But it fails to find a hyperlink text which is displayed on the page. I get Element not visible exception when I could actually see the link text on the screen. So, could anyone help me solve this issue or have any ideas that I could try?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and any error messages and the result.

Comment: Do you know if the element changes when it is at the mobile breakpoint? maybe it is hidden under a menu or something. Also is the element `display: none`? or is there some css that is making it invisible to webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's due to the time delay, that means code executes even before the link appears, So write the following code in your language

**Code from Ruby Selenium-binding**

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(timeout: 10) # seconds
wait.until { driver.find_element(id: "foo").displayed? }
driver.find_element(id: "foo").click
```

Comment: Tried implicit waits, explicit waits and also using sleep but none of them worked. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Shoby Did you use the wait for displayed as given in the answer or did you use the implicit wait only to element to exist ? The stress of the above comment is to wait until it displayed , did you use displayed ?

Comment: I get time-out exception which means it couldn't find the element and I shud increase the time?

Comment: @Shoby  Is it saying `unable to locate the element `?

Comment: I Get OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 50 seconds

Comment: @Shoby Ok, try this code var=driver.find_element(id: "foo") driver.execute_script("arguments[0].Click()",var)

Answer (score 0):

Try to scroll to the element.
You could use java script to do that.
In Python this can be done via
`WebDriver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)`

Answer (score 0):

Some elements of the DOM of the webpage change when you test for mobile responsiveness, so selenium is unable to locate the element that you are specifically trying to target.So, you should try to debug and find the methods where the code is failing to perform the action.Then you should find the locators for those elements in "mobile responsiveness view" and trigger only those methods when you are testing for mobile.